# How to make a refresh button in eclipse for an android application?

Tags: java, android

I wan to make a refresh button to refresh / update for the page when i press it. but i not sure how to do it. Pls give me some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reference http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidActionBar/article.html Look at section 5.3. But what are you trying to do. Have you written any code.